# IEnumerable extension method issue

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods, ienumerable

I have this IEnumerable extension method that was downloaded from the Internet and I am struggling to write a retrospective test that works

**Extension Method**

```
public static bool In<T>(this T source, params T[] list) where T : IEnumerable
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    return list.Contains(source);
}
```

**Test**

```
[TestMethod]
public void In()
{

    IEnumerable<int> search = new int[] { 0 };
    IEnumerable<int> found = new int[] { 0, 0, 1, 2, 3 };
    IEnumerable<int> notFound = new int[] { 1, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

    Assert.IsTrue(search.In(found));
    Assert.IsFalse(search.In(notFound));
}
```

**Results**

All the code compiles but in both assertions the result from the extension method returns false when I believe the first assertion `search.In(found)` should return true.

**Question**

Am I doing something wrong in the calling code or is there an issue with the extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work this test should look like:

```
[TestMethod]
public void In()
{

    IEnumerable<int> search = new int[] { 0 };
    IEnumerable<int> a = new int[] { 0, 0, 1, 2, 3 };
    IEnumerable<int> b = new int[] { 0, 0, 1, 2, 3 };
    IEnumerable<int> c = new int[] { 0};

    Assert.IsTrue(search.In(a,b,c));
    Assert.IsFalse(search.In(a,b));
}
```

It's because you are searching for whole array of int's here, not for items of them

In code above you are checking if in all passed parameters there is a array you are searching for

if you want extension which checks wheter item is on list try this:

```
public static bool In<T> (this T value, IEnumerable<T> list)
{
     return list.Contains(value);
}
```

and then you can do:

```
[TestMethod]
public void In()
{

    IEnumerable<int> search = 0;
    IEnumerable<int> found = new int[] { 0, 0, 1, 2, 3 };
    IEnumerable<int> notFound = new int[] { 1, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

    Assert.IsTrue(search.In(found));
    Assert.IsFalse(search.In(notFound));
}
```

EDIT:

thanks for comment Marcin

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek whoops

Answer (score 1):

Your `T` is `IEnumerable<int>` here, not `int`. Type the local variables as `int[]`. Right now you are invoking `In` with a single `IEnumerable<int>` in the params argument slot.

Taking another look the extension that you have there is bogus. Why should both the source and the search items (the params argument) both be `IEnumerable`? Makes no sense. Here is a working version:

```
    public static bool In<T>(this T operand, params T[] values) where T : IEquatable<T>
    {
        if (values == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("operand");

        return In(operand, ((IEnumerable<T>)values));
    }
    public static bool In<T>(this T operand, IEnumerable<T> values) where T : IEquatable<T>
    {
        if (values == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("operand");

        return values.Contains(operand);
    }
```

Comment: Gives me the same failure as previously where the first assertion fails

Comment: To make sure, try `In<int>`. That should work if your code is correct, or fail to compile if not.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check weather all elements in `source` are in `list`:

```
    public static bool In<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        return source.All(e => list.Contains(e));
    }

    IEnumerable<int> search = new int[] { 0 };
    IEnumerable<int> found = new int[] { 0, 0, 1, 2, 3 };
    IEnumerable<int> notFound = new int[] { 1, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

    Console.WriteLine(search.In(found));//True
    Console.WriteLine(search.In(notFound));//False
```